# Styling a MatHeaderCell dynamically with NgStyle?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, ng-style

I'm trying to provide dynamic styling to a `MatHeaderCell` instance like this:

```
[ngStyle]="styleHeaderCell(c)"
```

[I've created a demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-module-styling?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

I can see that:

```
styleHeaderCell(c)
```

Receives the column and returns and object however the style is not applied, and so the column still has a min width of `12rem` and I want it to be `4rem`.  Thoughts?

Comment: `mat-header-cell {
  width: 14rem;
}` You can only use this css class inside global `style.css` file and remove ngStyle part. Calling method from ngStyle is not good practive cause, angular will call this method each and every change detection.

Comment: I have a generic table component that is prebuilt with the pager, sorting, etc. and I need to be able to provide the styles as an input object.  Do you have a better way of rendering the settings via the `@Input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a syntax issue in your `styles` helper function.

Give this a try.

```
public styles: any = {
    ID: {
      'min-width': '4rem',
      'background-color': 'red'
    }
  };
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-module-styling-7vhrth?file=src/app/app.component.ts